# Python Multiprocessing iterates over script

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying my hands upon multiprocessing.pool, and it seems to work fine, except that whole script loops again and again.....

My code -

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

print "at top!"

arr = [30, 30, 30, 30]

def fib(num):
    if num == 0 or num == 1: return 1
    else: return (fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2))

def main():
    print "start"
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    result = [pool.apply_async(fib, args=(arr[i],)) for i in range(4)]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for res in result:
        print res.get()
    print "end"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


print "end of program ?"
```

And what it returns is this -

```
at top!
start
at top!
end of program ?
at top!
end of program ?
at top!
end of program ?
at top!
end of program ?
1346269
1346269
1346269
1346269
end
end of program ?
```

What I don't want is the repeating `at top !` and `end of program`.

I want the main program to freeze at that point and continue only after all the computations are finished.

PS. I am running it on windows 10, 64 - bit. Python 2.7 32 - bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange, when I run this (in python2.7) I only get `at top` and `end of program ?` once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's expected if you're running windows, the way that python windows spawns the processes: the script is imported as many times as there are spawned processes. So you cannot have only one `"at top"` print if you put unindented (at script top level). Same goes for `print "end of program ?"` of course.

(this doesn't happen on Linux which explains the comments of users saying that they cannot reproduce)

This is also why you had to protect your `main` with `if __name__ == '__main__'` test. So to get the expected output you'll have to do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("at top!")
    main()
    print("end of program")
```